# Como dividir uma string em array no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, string

Existe uma maneira elegante de dividir uma string em array baseando no exemplo:

```
var x = "FAT* FAT32*";
```

E que resulte em algo assim:

```
x[0] = "FAT*";
x[1] = "FAT32*";
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim, há, é usando o [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var x = "FAT* FAT32*";
var array = x.split(" ");
console.log(array[0]);
console.log(array[1]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Split.js).

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar o método [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) como já mencionado, junto com a expressão `\s+`, que irá corresponder a um ou mais espaços.

```js
var str = "FAT* FAT32*";
var match = str.split(/\s+/);

alert(match[0]);
alert(match[1]);
```

Uma alternativa é obter esses valores através da [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/([\w\*]+)/g`, que corresponderá caracteres alfanuméricos e asterisco.

```js
var str = "FAT* FAT32*";
var match = str.match(/([\w\*]+)/g);

alert(match[0]);
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `split()`

```
console.log(x.split(" "))
//resultado deverá ser ["FAT*", "FAT32*"]
```

também o `slice()`

```
 var z = x.slice(0,4)
 var y = x.slice(4)
 var d = []
 d.push(z)
 d.push(y)
 console.log(d)
 //resultado deverá ser ["FAT*", "FAT32*"]
```